# Testing controller get return value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

How do I get the return value from this test? My controller returns `@Responsebody Meal`

```
@Test
// @Transactional
public void testPost() {

    Profile profile = ProfileUtil.getProfile();
    profileService.save(profile);

    String requestUri = "/user/" + profile.getId() + "/meals";

    request.setMethod("POST");
    request.setRequestURI(requestUri);
    Object handler;

    try {

        handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
        handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

        //I would like to have the controller return value here! :) 
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

- call the controller directly instead of going through the handler mapping/servlet layer. This way you'll simply get the `Meal` object and you can run assertions on it
- parse the response from `response` object. In your case `Meal` object was taken by Spring MVC and marshalled, probably to XML or JSON. The original object is now lost, you can only retrieve the XML/JSON string, parse it and run assertions on it (e.g. using XPath).

Both approaches have their advantages. Prefer the first one if you want to test the controller itself. The latter is more complex but lets you test marshalling.